# <format> header not found (C++)

Tags: c++, c++20

I want to use the new C++20 `<format>` header. But when I try to `#include` it, it apparently doesn't exist in my current stdlib.

I tried using clang++ and g++, but neither of them work.

Yes, I specified the C++ standard to be "c++2a" in the `tasks.json` file in VSCode.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can view an overview of compiler support here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support

According to the table, up to today (May 13 '20 at 8:07) no compiler supports P0645R10: Text formatting.

The overview specifically for MSVS can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=vs-2019 (though I didn't find `<format>` on their list).

Comment: If no compiler exists which supports format, then how are you supposed to use it? Or why does it even exist?

Comment: @Hellstormer support for C++20 is rapidly growing, you need to check your compilers news and stay tuned. Things will change in the coming months

Comment: It exists because it will be supported but not yet.

Comment: @Hellstormer " Or why does it even exist?" I dont understand.. what exists is the standard that specifies what the header should contain, thats not the same as having it ready to be used

Comment: @Hellstormer I also dont know all the details. Sometimes new additions to the standard library are coming via boost. Afaik an example implementation has to exist for a proposal to be accepted, but propososals go trhough a long process including potential modifications before actually included in the standard. I didnt check, but I wouldnt be surprised if `<format>` is very similar to Boost::format, and probably you can find most things there already